# Inno Setup RegAsm.exe Errors

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am trying to build a 32/64bit installer all in one. The only thing that is different on a 32bit vs. a 64bit machine is a call to RegAsm.exe. For a 64bit machine that code has to look at the 64bit framework and for a 32bit it looks at the standard framework.

32bit:
"C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework"
64bit:
"C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64";

I have my package setup to run Install actions. For my 64bit action I have the check enable for IsWin64.

Filename: {dotnet4064}\Regasm.exe; Parameters: """mydll.dll"" /codebase"; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: "Registering Add-In"; Flags: RunHidden; Check: IsWin64;

Several lines of the log file before the error

```
2012-12-05 14:58:53.233   Installing the file.
2012-12-05 14:58:53.281   Successfully installed the file.
2012-12-05 14:58:53.281   -- Icon entry --
2012-12-05 14:58:53.281   Filename: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\myprogram\my program\Uninstall  myprogram.lnk
2012-12-05 14:58:53.281   Creating directory: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\myprogram\my program
2012-12-05 14:58:53.483   -- Icon entry --
2012-12-05 14:58:53.483   Filename: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\myprogram\my program\myprogram.lnk
2012-12-05 14:58:54.224   -- Icon entry --
2012-12-05 14:58:54.224   Filename: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\myprogram.lnk
2012-12-05 14:58:54.281   Fatal exception during installation process (Exception):
                          Internal error: Cannot run files in 64-bit locations on this version of Windows.
2012-12-05 14:58:54.281   Exception message:
2012-12-05 14:58:54.281   Message box (OK):
                          Internal error: Cannot run files in 64-bit locations on this version of Windows.
2012-12-05 14:58:54.926   User chose OK.
2012-12-05 14:58:54.926   Message box (OK):
                          Setup was not completed.

                          Please correct the problem and run Setup again.
2012-12-05 14:59:00.222   User chose OK.
2012-12-05 14:59:00.222   Rolling back changes.
```

This all works fine on a 64bit machine. In a 32bit machine I get an error:

**Internal Error: Cannot run files in 64-bit locations on this version of Windows**

I've been all over the help documentation and google and cannot lock down a reason as to why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{dotnet40}\Regasm.exe"; Parameters: "My.TaskPane.dll"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: "Registering MyTaskPane Add-In"
Filename: "{dotnet4064}\Regasm.exe"; Parameters: "My.TaskPane.dll"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: "Registering My TaskPane Add-In"; Check: IsWin64
Filename: "{dotnet40}\Regasm.exe"; Parameters: "My.TaskPane.dll /codebase"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: "Registering My TaskPane Add-In"
Filename: "{dotnet4064}\Regasm.exe"; Parameters: "My.TaskPane.dll /codebase"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: "Registering My TaskPane Add-In"; Check: IsWin64
Filename: "{app}\My Software Suite.exe"; Parameters: "/register"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: PostInstall; Description: "Register the My Software Suite"
```

I resolved this by adding: ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64 and then using Check: Is64BitInstallMode

Comment: Grab a installation log and show the relevant lines before the error occurs.

Comment: This is the response from the log. Doesn't tell anything really past the error the dialog mentions.
2012-12-05 14:58:54.281   Fatal exception during installation process (Exception):
                          Internal error: Cannot run files in 64-bit locations on this version of Windows.
2012-12-05 14:58:54.281   Exception message:
2012-12-05 14:58:54.281   Message box (OK):
                          Internal error: Cannot run files in 64-bit locations on this version of Windows.
2012-12-05 14:58:54.926   User chose OK.

Comment: The low shows the installer is executing the RegAsm.exe that is not supposed to do?

Comment: The log doesn't show the action for regasm.exe. The logical location for it would be where the error is. Right before the error the installer makes the shortcut icons on the desktop and start menu (which works). The error doesn't show anything in regards to regasm.exe after the icons, just that there is a failure (listed above).

Comment: Does the log show a -- Run entry -- before the error? nothing? You should update your question with 10 or so lines of the log before the error occurs.

Comment: I did as you request. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: In the current source code, the message is generated only in a call inside the ProcessRunEntry procedure in Main.pas. There are some unconditional calls to the Log procedure before the exception is raised, but your log doesn't show that. What version of inno setup are you using? Unicode or not?

Comment: It is 5.4.3(a). How do I tell if it is unicode or not?

Comment: Just upgraded to 5.5.2 non-unicode, will test and let you know.

Comment: Post your entire `[Run]` section.  Also let us know whether you've specified `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` or not, and if so, what it's set to.

Comment: I added the [Run] section per your request.

Comment: @user is the second time I edit your question to add proper code formatting. Please take a moment to look at the markdown to learn how it works and post it correctly your next time. (in case of code, just add four blank spaces at the beginning of each line, the {} button does it automatically for a selected block).

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that... New to posting on the forum.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by adding: ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64 and then using Check: Is64BitInstallMode